# php error tracking

Tags: php, tracking

i am using php and mysql for my projects with pear package.

i want to track bugs in my programs .

is there any way to track a bug in pear package or php5.

suppose in my program any error or warning is generate then i want to track this error and

store into database.

any one have idea about it.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Do not store errors in the database. many errors are database related itself. what would you do with it?

PHP already have everything you want. just turn on `log_errors` ini directive and, optionally,  `error_log` one to specify certain log file instead of placing PHP errors in the web-server's log file

Also you may find useful a `trigger_error()` function which could bring a custom message to the standard error output, e.g

```
mysql_error($sql);
if(!$sql) trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);
```

Comment: Then parse that log file every N hours and load it into the database for later error reporting.

Comment: I agree with Col. Shrapnel here, you don't want to keep track of errors that happened in an application by means of that same application.

Comment: To answer your question "what would you do with it"; to easier manage info, warnings and error messages. Because reading through log files isn't always very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing the error details into your own database you should use an error tracking service.

The problem of tracking your own errors in the same system is problematic: The chances are high that it cannot store them, because of the same reason the error occurred itself. Like the database has a deadlock or other errors. Parsing your log file may be ok, but you would only know about the error with a big delay and probably miss valuable information.

Some other advantages:

- It groups the errors to similar error groups
- You will be notified about new errors in real-time
- You see how often and when an error occurred

I'm the founder of [Exceptiontrap](https://exceptiontrap.com) with its [PHP library](https://github.com/itmLABS/exceptiontrap-php), but there are other services, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **find bugs faster**, you should consider using [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org). It provides more output on errors and allows you to debug the application step-by-step.

If you need to **log exceptions**, you can use some logger, like [Zend_Log](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.log.html), to write logs with specific application data. You can even specify message importance level to leave out debug data on production systems.

Also, I would recommend using [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com) together with [Firephp](http://www.firephp.org/). This way you can get debug data easily without using `print_r` and the likes.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Sentry](http://vimeo.com/15235999). It's written in Python, but you could [write a PHP client](http://readthedocs.org/docs/sentry/en/latest/client/index.html) for it. I couldn't find one myself, so please lemme know if you find/code one.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a powerful error tracking library which allows you to track errors in your application using a single API to any or all of services like Exceptiontrap, Sentry, Raygun, Airbrake AND local resources like logs, emails, databases and FirePHP. Check it